# How to read from redis replica with go-redis

Tags: kubernetes, redis, go-redis

We have a go lang service which will go to redis, to fetch data for each request and we want to read data from redis slave node as well. We went through the documentation of redis and go-redis library and found that, in order to read data from redis slave we should fire readonly command from redis side. We are using ClusterOptions on go-redis library to setup a readonly connection to redis.

```
redis.NewClusterClient(&redis.ClusterOptions{
    Addrs:    []string{redisAddress},
    Password: "",
    ReadOnly: true,
})
```

After doing all this we are able to see (Using monitoring) that read requests are handled by master nodes only. I hope this is not expected and I am missing something or doing it wrong. Any pointers will be appreciated to solve this problem.

Some more context:
redisAddress in above code is single kubernetes cluster IP. Redis is deployed using kubernetes operator with 3 masters and 1 replica for each master.

Answer (score 1):

I`ve done it setting the option RouteRandomly: true

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).